# struct initialization in c++ error

Tags: c++, constructor, struct

I'm new to c++, I run the following code in visual studio c++

```
    struct bob
    {
       double a,b;      
       bob(double a,double b);
    }

    int main()
    {
        bob z(2.2,5.6);
        cout<<z.a<<endl;
        keep_window_open();
        return 0;
    }
```

when I run this code, i get the following error:

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall bob::bob(double,double)" (??0bob@@QAE@NN@Z) referenced in function _main  C:\drives\Comp-Mech\programming\V.S\C++\projects\E1\E1.obj  E1

Comment: You only declare `bob(double a,double b);`, where is your implementation?

Comment: feature request for C++17: automatic constructor generation from its declaration when written as `bob(double, double) = default;` and signature matches data members.

Comment: @rhalbersma: Why? Why not just drop the constructor altogether and use aggregate initialization?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas that would not work for private `class` data members

Comment: @rhalbersma: Which is not the code in question. Your suggestion has many potentials for failure (roughly the same as aggregate initialization). I don't see that getting through the standard committee, but go ahead and propose it :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Why would that be the case? After all, after user-defining `bob(double, double)` the pitfalls are exactly the same when writing `bob{3.0, 1.0}`, aren't they? I haven't thought about complications with nested aggregates and so on, but if you would like to anwer that, I can post a separate question on whether compiler generation of complete member initializer constructors would be a good idea or not.

Comment: @rhalbersma: Yes, the pitfalls are exactly the same which means no better :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas IMO the aggregate issues of **using** such constructors are orthogonal to whether the compiler or the user should have to **define** them. `=default` syntax would only explicitly request something that can unambiguously be defined. it's not like I'm proposing implicitly generated multi-argument constructors :-)

Comment: @rhalbersma: Yes, but the request for the feature and where issues can crop are separate places, which makes this as dangerous as aggregate initialization. Say that you have a type `struct X { char ch, int a; double d; }; ` for which you use this feature and you call `X x(65,32,3)` somewhere else in the code. Now someone notices that you waste space and reorders the members: `struct X { double d; int a; char ch; };`. User code that expected `x.ch == 'A';` now sees `x.ch == ' '` (assuming ASCII). If you provided the constructor yourself it wouldn't matter, all initialization is *named*

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas fair point, although the guy doing the reordering would also be likely to reorder a user-defined constructor's signature to reflect the data members order, so at the remote call site there would still be a problem. But I agree, it would not be a good proposal.

Comment: @rhalbersma: The order in the initialization list only matters if members depend on other members, which if you have the option of having the *defaulted* version, cannot be the case.

Answer (score 5):

You need to implement constructor of your class bob:

```
 bob::bob(double a,double b) : a(a), b(b) {}
```

Comment: There's a colon missing though.

Comment: @piokuc Interesting, so the class members are not visible inside the parens. Or is it that the params shadow them?

Comment: It's not that they are not visible, but they are shadowed by the constructor's parameters. It does work, believe me, or test it ;)

Comment: @piokuc, Yes that should be obvious. Not sure why I had that wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You have provided a declaration for `bob`'s constructor, but you have not given a definition. The definition gives the implementation of the constructor and says exactly what it should do. In this case, you likely want your constructor to assign its arguments to the object's member variables:

```
bob::bob(double a, double b)
{
  this->a = a;
  this->b = b;
}
```

I used assignment in the above code because you are more likely to be familiar with it. However, you should be aware of member initialization lists which allow you to initialize members directly:

```
bob::bob(double a, double b)
  : a(a), b(b)
{ }
```

This says to initialise the member `a` with the argument `a` and initialise member `b` with the argument `b`. It also avoids potentially expensive default initialization of members before assigning to them.

Comment: This is a struct, so no need for explicit public

Comment: @piokuc Noticed that immediately after saying it.

Comment: you might mention that for user-defined types with default constructors, the member initializer is also more efficient since it avoid double initialization

Comment: I won't, although I feel like downvoting for proposing assignments and defending it with a *To keep it simple*. Initialization lists are just as simple if people see and use them from the beginning, it is this kind of *simpler if doing assingment* that ends with tutorials teaching bad practice before telling people what the right thing to do is.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Reworded. Didn't mean to suggest it was simpler to do that, just simpler to understand for the asker.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you haven't written the code for `bob::bob(double, double)`.

```
struct bob
{
   double a,b;      
   bob(double aa, double bb) a(aa), b(bb) {}
};
```